# jQuery Animation not applying for a link?

Tags: jquery

I have had some help here about showing and hiding div's the following code has been created as a result, which works great, the only problem is when i click a link with the class .closepanel the slideup animation doesn't work e.g. the animation is not applied when it closes... seems strange as the closing animation does apply for clicks anywhere else...

Especially as it shares the function to slideup as the one that works...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#panel').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });      
  $(".panel-tab").click(function(e) {
    $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $(document,'.closepanel').click(function() {
      $("#panel").slideUp("slow");
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Now I might remember wrong. But I think that if you limit your search with an argument to JQuery, that argument should be the **second** argument. But since you use **document** you are not actually limiting it very much.

So, either of these should probably work

```
$('.closepanel').click(function() {
      $("#panel").slideUp("slow");
  });
```

or if you really want to reference the **document**

```
$('.closepanel', document).click(function() {
      $("#panel").slideUp("slow");
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for post, this doesn't work i'm affraid. Still the same animation.

Comment: So the **#closepanel** does NOT slide up when **.closepanel** is clicked? Where is the **#closepanel** located? It might be that your click is actually firing another function or event if it resides within another element that contains a function or event listner.

Comment: i've tried .closepanel (The link to close #panel) - both inside and outside #panel but to to avail... As my original code stands, you can click anywhere outside #anel to close it, but i also want a .closepanel link within #panel so uses can close it that way as well. - But in doing so, upon clicking .closepanel the slideup animation doesn't work and it simply closeses it.

Comment: The problem is that you have a huge negatvie **left-margin** and thus your text ends up out of view. Try setting your **left-margin** to **0 px** and you will see your text and if you click on it you will also see that the animation works. You might also wan't to add a **#** to the **href** of your close link. Try positioning the div using another method than a negative margin.

Comment: Solved! lol - the issue was the "#" needed to be added to the link! Thanks

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it helped you. A low frequency of accepted answers will lead to it being harder to get replies on questions and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument list in the selector is the wrong way around for this line:

```
$(document,'.closepanel')
```

the context argument should be second:

```
$('.closepanel', document)
```

Which will select elements with the class `closepanel` in the context of `document`.

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/ for more details on the context parameter.

---

Update:
To select everything but `.closepanel` use:

```
$(document).Remove('.closepanel')
```

or

```
$('*:not(.closepanel)')
```

Then bind your event handlers.

See: http://api.jquery.com/remove/ and http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/ for more information

---

Update 2:

If you are wanting to build a collection to bind a handler that slides the panel up, you can:

- combine using multiple selectors: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/
- use `.add(selector)` to add to the selected items http://api.jquery.com/add/
- create the function as a variable and bind the events seperately

You can also use `one()` http://api.jquery.com/one/ to bind a handler to an event to run once to prevent side effects of slideup() being called when the panel is not shown.

Comment: I'm affraid that causes the "click anywhere" function not to work and the .closepanel still just closes

Comment: Hi, Thanks for such a swift response,  the scenario is: I have a slidedown menu, that closes when a user clicks anywhere outside the box, but I aalso want a "closepanel" button inside the dropped panel so they can close it that way as well...but the scroll up animation when you click this doesn't scroll.... it simply closes straight away..... any ideas please?

Comment: update 2: - Thanks, as i've shown in my code, i've tried multiple selectors... There must be a strange conflict somewhere, or i'll have to live with the closing (though i don't really want to) - as I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Have you stepped through this function under both an outside click and the button click to check the differences? Sorry most of my answer is about selectors which you already have done.

Comment: It sure does work! Thanks for your efforts, it turns out # just needed to be added to the link lol! thanks again.